# How can I say "all these tasks should have this tag" when including yml files?

Tags: ansible

In my `roles/common/main.yml` I have `- include ruby2.yml`.  That file has 3-4 tasks and each one has `tags: ruby2`.  Works fine, but feels repetitive.  The documentation says that when doing the include I could write it like this: `- include: ruby2.yml tags=ruby2`

But that puts the responsibility outside of the file itself which bugs me for some reason.

Is there a way, within `ruby2.yml` to say "all of these tasks should have the 'ruby2' tag?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leucos' answer is actually *incorrect*.

```
- include: ruby2.yml tags=ruby2
```

The above will tag every task in `ruby2.yml` with the `ruby2` tag, just as OP already mentioned.

This is clearly and explicitly [documented here](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_tags.html).

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but where on that page does it clearly state that?  I could read it both ways..?

Comment: > Both of these have the function of tagging every single task inside the include statement.
   
I don't see any ambiguity in the above sentence. Still, you can see an official example here:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/tags.yml#L42

This line includes `tasks/base.yml` and tags it with `base`. Notice that there is no tag decleration in [tasks/base.yml](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/tasks/base.yml) whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to do that, and this is infortunate !

Note that

```
- include: ruby2.yml tags=ruby2
```

means "from ruby2.yml import tasks that have the 'ruby2' tag". It does not apply a tag to all actions.

Comment: Oof.  That was misleading then.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes ! Same for me. When I saw the 'tags=', I was also full of hope :s